# Keeping form values after POST

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a form, which on submitted goes to a php file and inserts values into DB(MySql).After successfully inserting values into DB, I want to return back to form screen, with values previously entered and posted. 
Actually I am using the below code to return back to form page, but am unable to load fields with previous values.

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1; URL=form.php'>";
```

form.php file contains form and add_form.php adds values to database. The above code is written in add_form.php on sql query success

Suggest me an easier way of doing this

Comment: Either post to the same php file that has the form html and the processing code, so you dont need to redirect. Or save the values into $_SESSION.

Comment: Am already posting values from form.php to the add_form.php and now u are asking me to post values back to form.php

Comment: Make sure you sanitize the inputs before putting them into the DB _and_ before putting them back into the form fields.

Comment: @user3549665 No, im suggesting you post to form.php and do away with add_form.php. Or use sessions.

Comment: Why don't you just use your added mysql data? After adding a data to your db, get it and send it back to your view.

Answer (score 0):

In your add_form.php after saving data you can redirect like this.

```
$url = 'form.php?'.http_build_query($_POST);
header('Refresh:5; url= $url');
```

And in your form.php you can do this.

```
<input type="text" name="something" value="<?php echo $_GET['something']; ?>" />
```

Comment: @user3549665 u[dated my answer. Now you can display information and it will redirect in 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it when I need to retain data that is posted via PHP form

```
if (isset($_POST['your_button_name'])) {
        foreach ($_POST as $field => $value)
            $this->settings[$field] = $value;
}
```

and if I need to refer, I simply do `$this->settings['field_name']`

note: you will ofcourse have to define variable `$settings` and make sure to sanitize the data

Answer (score -1):

you can try JavaScript ajax to do this～